# Is there a definitive set of monster icons or images that is royalty free?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, intellectual-property, roll20, art

I'm about to start broadcasting a D&D campaign on roll20 via twitch.tv. My current account is loaded with images that are, suffice to say, copyright infringement. I intend to replace all of the images with something that doesn't infringe a copyright: preferably something that Wizards (or a fan) has published for this similar purpose.

The major issue is that preload all of my monsters ahead of time, and I homebrew quite a few of them, so it would be a lot of work up front for me to draw my own. I can't use roll20's images, because as soon as I add something that doesn't already exist, the whole system becomes inconsistent. I can't seem to find any shortcuts for this.

My preferred answer would be any free-to-use icon set that encompasses monster types (Aberration, Beast, Celestial, Construct...) or any resource that simply entails a variety of monsters without violating a copyright.

Comment: Hi Robert--it's proven tough to handle questions that are explicitly asking for recommendations as their answers. However, if you can rewrite the question to be about your *problem* (I want to stream my R20 game, their icon set isn't sufficient for me, I can't generate my own) then the *answers* can either make recommendations or not. I.e. one answer might be "I had this problem and commissioned icons from this artist" while another is "there's a great set of freely-usable icons I use over at this location." Recommendations are fine *answers*, difficult *questions.*

Answer (score 0):

No. To my knowledge, there are no such royalty free libraries you would likely want to use. There are several libraries with stock photos and art that have one time fees or complex contract fees.

You may be able to petition a group of artists to allow you to advertise their work in your TV show. Alternatively, you can use fundme/patron sites to fund raise for artist fees.

Reconstructing all the art yourself, by the time you finish, would take years, no matter what method you used, such as tracing existing still frames of an open source 3D .stl file or film of a bird flying through the air, using a WACOM graphics tablet. By the time you are done spending the time and money on this cheap knock off art, you could have paid for a stock library account several times over.

Your most entertaining possibility is spending money attending a comic, science fiction/fantasy, or gaming convention, then hunting down artists in person and working something out with them. That will only cost the price of admission plus whatever they want to charge, you can use your videos as free advertising for them, as the mechanism of "payment".